# Absolute position regulation NXC

Tags: nxt, nxc

I am trying to position the LEGO NXT motor exactly at a certain absolute angle:

```
PosRegEnable (OUT_A);  
PosRegSetAngle (OUT_A, 0);  
Wait (500);                  // to read sensor value  
PosRegSetAngle (OUT_A, 90);  
Wait (500);                  // to read sensor value  
PosRegSetAngle (OUT_A, 180);  
Wait (500);                  // to read sensor value
```

My Brick has V1.31 firmware.

When I load this program and run it, it doesn't display any error but the motor doesn't run.

Has someone experienced this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs (emphasis added):

> Warning
>
> This function requires the **enhanced** NBC/NXC firmware version 1.31+

Make sure you are using the **enhanced** firmware provided with NXC and not the *official* firmware from LEGO.